# Do I need to file 8606 amendment to correct "total basis in traditional IRAs" value?

Tags: united-states, ira, irs

[Form 8606 line 2:](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8606.pdf)

> Enter your total basis in traditional IRAs. See instructions .

This value was entered as 0 but it should not be. Otherwise, everything else is same. Do I need to file form 8606 amending this value?

From what I see on IRS website at [Amending Form 8606](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i8606#en_US_2021_publink25399ed0e1098), it is not required but I am not so good at reading these tax docs. Can someone confirm? Thanks!

Comment: Was entered by whom? Why shouldn't it be?

Comment: @littleadv I am second guessing my CPA work, who did few mistakes in the past and decided to educate my self(you can see that from my recent posts :))

Also, you got me thinking, maybe this should be 0 as whatever was there in Traditional IRA was transferred to Roth IRA once money settled in there. What do you suggest?

Comment: "basis" is the amount of non-deductible contributions still left in your traditional IRA. I don't know your situation, I don't know if you still have basis in your IRA. Your CPA might know better than me. Why don't you ask him how he reached the numbers that he reached?

Comment: I think what is left in Traditional IRA is key.. That is why my CPA might have entered 0. Thanks for talking me through it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you _ever_ make a contribution to your Traditional IRA for which you _did not_ take a tax deduction,  a.k.a. report on Form 1040 as an adjustment to income and thus not have that money taxed as income? As you splutter "Why would I not take the deduction?", please bear in mind that people with high income are not allowed to make tax-_deductible_ contributions to Traditional IRAs, but some _choose_ to make a contribution anyway, not take the tax deduction, and thus create what is called a _basis_ in your IRA, money that will not be taxed when you take it out later. Did you ever do this?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Did you ever make a contribution to your Traditional IRA for which you did not take a tax deduction — YES


1) I contributed to Traditional IRA 2) Transferred that money to Roth IRA the next day 3) Didn’t show the money I contributed to Traditional IRA as deduction on 1040.

Comment: Did you have _other_ Traditional IRA accounts with nonzero balances, not necessarily with the same custodian when you pulled the "backdoor Roth IRA" trick? Also, did you file Form 8606 for the year(s?) when you did the backdoor Roth IRA? Did you get a Form 1099-R each time?

Comment: @DilipSarwate 
Did you have other Traditional IRA accounts with nonzero balances, not necessarily with the same custodian when you pulled the "backdoor Roth IRA" trick? -- `No`
Also, did you file Form 8606 for the year(s?) when you did the backdoor Roth IRA? -- `Yes`
Did you get a Form 1099-R each time? -- `Yes`